# Problem with using multiple inputs for the same output

Tags: python, if-statement

I am making a calculator to determine proper weightlifting categories.

```
if gender == "male" or "m" and skillLevel < 6:
    evaluation = beginnerM
if gender == "male" or "m" and 6 <= skillLevel < 24:
    evaluation = noviceM
if gender == "male" or "m" and 24 <= skillLevel < 60:
    evaluation = intermediateM
if gender == "male" or "m" and skillLevel >= 60:
    evaluation = advancedM

if gender == "female" or "f" and skillLevel < 6:
    evaluation = beginnerF
if gender == "female" or "f" and 6 <= skillLevel < 24:
    evaluation = noviceF
if gender == "female" or "f" and 24 <= skillLevel < 60:
    evaluation = intermediateF
if gender == "female" or "f" and skillLevel >= 60:
    evaluation = advancedF
```

For some reason my shortened versions "m" and "f" are causing problems in including them. The code works fine when I instruct code to only take the longer versions "male" and "female" but when I use [or] to tell the code to take both of them as viable it just takes both inputs as the "female" version of them. This is confusing me more than it should

Comment: The problem is that `if gender == "male" or "m"` is treated as two completely separate conditions `gender == "male"` and `"m"`.  And of course `"m"` by itself is a non-empty string, so it is always true.  See the linked duplicate.